# How to ignore system stores when decrypting and checking signature in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, cryptography, ssl-certificate, x509certificate

I need to decrypt messages and verify signature in .NET application.

I tried to use EnvelopedCms.Decrypt(X509Certificate2Collection) and SignedCms.CheckSignature(X509Certificate2Collection, bool). These methods work well, however they treat the certificate collection as **additional** certificates; they always use certificates from system store as well.

Is there a standard way to decrypt and verify signature using **only** the provided certificate collection? I have several certificates in the system store and messages signed by client A should be rejected if they come from client B.

Answer (score 0):

You will probably need to define a custom-validation method:

Check this link: http://8r13n.wordpress.com/2007/07/24/bypassing-certificate-validation-in-net/

A dummy implementation would be something like this:

```
public static bool TrustAllCertificatesCallback(
        object sender, X509Certificate cert,
        X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors errors)
{
    return true;
}
```

And then you would set the value of `ServerCertificateValidationCallback`:

```
// Call this at the start of your app
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback =
            TrustAllCertificatesCallback;
```

**UPDATE**

If you want to check the sender of a `SignedCms` you can use the [`Certificates` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.security.cryptography.pkcs.signedcms.certificates%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), which will hold the client's certificates.

Comment: This callback seems to apply only to certificate validation performed indirectly during SSL exchange. I decrypt data directly, so this callback never gets called.

Comment: If you want to validate the client that sent a packet, you can find it's certificate at the `Certificates` property of `SignedCms` (this is actually a collection, use the `0`th element).

Comment: Yes, this seems to do what I need. Not very elegant, but if there are no other options, I'll have to do it this way.

Comment: I'll include it in the answer for completeness :P; if you don't mind, if you find a better way, answer your own question; this was the way to validate the sender of a packet that I learnt at school.

Comment: Sure. I have put this task away for a while, but as soon as I get it working, I'll post the code here.